# Moving files after comparing filenames and recreating source directories

Tags: bash, awk, find, printf, posix

I'm learning shell scripting, and am striving to remain as POSIX compliant as possible while keeping the code-base somewhat readable.  The goal is to read a list of files from directory A, find their matches from directory B, and recreate a portion of the directory parent B in directory C where the files from directory A should be moved, then remove the matched/moved files from directory B, and if the directories are then empty from directory B files found, remove them.  All files in directory A will always be unique to each other, and there will always be one or more matches from directory B and never a match in directory C, but the sub-directories in directory C may already be present to match from directory B.  All files matched in Directory B should be removed after matches are moved from Directory A to Directory C.  Extensions change as files are processed separately, but filenames will otherwise match exactly.  Filenames may contain spaces and periods.  Filenames will not always be the same length.  There are two levels of sub-directories in the output and archive directories.

Here's what I've got so far.  I'm getting stuck on writing the for-loop to do the dirty work.  Trying not to step too far outside of find, printf, awk, grep, for, and if.

```
#!/bin/sh
execHome="intendedMachine"
baseDir="/home/library/projects"
folderNew="output"
folderOld="working"
folderArchive="archive"
workingTypes=("jpg", "svg", "bmp", "tiff", "psd")

$folderNew="$baseDir/$folderNew"
$folderOld="$baseDir/$folderOld"
folderArchive="$baseDir/$folderArchive"

if [ "$(uname -n)" = "$execHome" ]
then

  count=$(find $folderNew -type f |grep -v "DS_Store" |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'|wc -l)

  printf "\nFound/processing %s files in the %s folder\n\n" "$count" "$folderNew"

  find $folderNew -type f |grep -v "DS_Store" |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'

else
  printf "Executed from %s; Run from %s for proper execution.\n" "$(uname -n)" "$execHome"
fi
```

---

Example:

Directory A

```
/home/library/projects/output/projectOne 1.a.png
/home/library/projects/output/projectOne 1.b.png
/home/library/projects/output/projectOne 1.c.png
/home/library/projects/output/projectThree 3.m.png
/home/library/projects/output/projectThree 3.o.png
/home/library/projects/output/projectFour 4.t.png
/home/library/projects/output/projectFour 4.u.png
```

Directory B

```
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.a.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.a.svg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.b.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.b.svg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.c.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.g.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.g.svg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.h.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.h.svg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.i.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.m.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.n.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.o.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.o.svg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 04/projectFour 4.s.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 04/projectFour 4.t.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 04/projectFour 4.u.jpg
```

Directory C

```
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.d.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.e.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.f.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.p.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.q.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.r.png
```

---

Desired outcome:

Directory A files have been moved to Directory C

```
/home/library/projects/output/
```

Directory B should have Directory A files removed and empty folders deleted

```
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.g.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.g.svg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.h.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.h.svg
/home/library/projects/working/House/2018 02/projectTwo 2.i.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.n.jpg
/home/library/projects/working/Car/2018 04/projectFour 4.s.jpg
```

Directory C should contain both old archives and new output files as archives

```
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.a.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.b.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.c.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.d.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.e.png
/home/library/projects/archive/House/2018 01/projectOne 1.f.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.m.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.o.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.p.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.q.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 03/projectThree 3.r.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 04/projectFour 4.t.png
/home/library/projects/archive/Car/2018 04/projectFour 4.u.png
```

---

Ran the code anyway from a bash 4.4.19 machine to see how it does, but it didn't work quite like I expected.  Here's the resultant output:

```
Found/processing 4 files in the /home/library/projects/output folder

./auto-archive.sh: line 34: hash["$proj"]: bad array subscript
parent of /home/library/projects/output/.temp/projectThree 3.m.png not found
parent of /home/library/projects/output/projectOne 1.a.png not found
parent of /home/library/projects/output/.temp/projectThree 3.0.png not found
parent of /home/library/projects/output/projectFour 4.t.png not found
```

My apologies.  I also didn't mention earlier that Directory B should not be scanned recursively, which in the use-case yields other temporary files that are being written, but may not yet be ready to move.  Also, for the purposes of testing, only the four files listed above were actually in Directory A; not all the files listed initially.  Further, after recreating the proposed test structure, your code seems to execute flawlessly; not matching the results from my actual file structure.  I fear I may have missed some crucial element in describing my actual file structure/naming convention.  Reviewing now for descriptor differences.  Sorry to be taking time away, but certainly impressed with your accuracy.  Feels like we're getting close, but definitely need to run on earlier version of bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task will be divided into three steps:

1. To create a map which associates each filename (project name) to its parent directory name in C. This is performed as a preparation stage by analyzing pathnames in B. We will make use of an associative array and **the bash version must be 4.2 or newer**.
2. To loop over the files in A, compose a path name to be stored in C by using the map created in the 1st step, and remove files in B.
3. As a clean-up stage, we remove empty directories in B, if any.

Then how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

execHome="intendedMachine"
baseDir="/home/library/projects"
folderNew="output"
folderOld="working"
folderArchive="archive"
workingTypes=("jpg" "svg" "bmp" "tiff" "psd")
declare -A hash

folderNew="$baseDir/$folderNew"
folderOld="$baseDir/$folderOld"
folderArchive="$baseDir/$folderArchive"

if [ "$(uname -n)" != "$execHome" ]; then
    printf "Executed from %s; Run from %s for proper execution.\n" "$(uname -n)" "$execHome"
    exit
fi

count=$(find "$folderNew" -type f |grep -v "DS_Store" |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'|wc -l)
printf "\nFound/processing %s files in the %s folder\n\n" "$count" "$folderNew"

# determine parent directory name for each project name and create a map for them
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0' f; do 
    proj="${f##*/}"         # remove dirname
    proj="${proj%.*}"               # remove extention
    parent="${f##*$baseDir/}"       # remove pathname until $baseDir
    parent="${parent#*/}"   # strip pathname one-level deeper
    parent="${parent%/*}"   # remove filename
    # now we're mapping "projectOne 1.a" => "House/2018 01" e.g.
#   echo "$proj" "=>" "$parent"     # just for debugging
    hash["$proj"]="$parent"
done < <(find "$folderOld" -type f -print0) # directory B

# iterate over files in A; move to archive directory C and remove files in B
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    proj="${f##*/}"
    proj="${proj%.*}"
    parent="${hash[$proj]}"
    if [[ "$parent" = "" ]]; then
    echo "parent of $f not found"   # may not occur but just in case ..
    else
    # move from A to C
    destdir="$folderArchive/$parent"
    mkdir -p -- "$destdir"
    mv -- "$f" "$destdir"

    # remove relevant file(s) in B
    for ext in "${workingTypes[@]}"; do
        oldfile="$folderOld/$parent/$proj.${ext}"
        [ -f "$oldfile" ] && rm -f -- "$oldfile"
    done
    fi
done < <(find "$folderNew" -type f -print0) # directory A

# clean-up: remove empty dirs in B
find "$folderOld" -type d -empty -print0 | xargs -r -0 rmdir --
```

**Explanations:**

- You do not have to use commas to split elements in an array.
- You should not put `$` prior to the variable name on the left-hand side.
- The `while IFS= ... done < <(find ...)` syntax is an idiom to loop over the output of `find`.
- The `${parameter#word}` type of syntax is a `parameter expansion` to extract a substring from the path.
- The associative array `hash` maps each project name, such as "projectOne 1.a" to its parent directory name, such as "House/2018 01".
- `--`s in some commands are to prepare for the filenames which may start with `-`. (this protection may look pathological...)

If your bash is older than 4.2, let me know. Then we need to find an alternative.

**EDIT**
Here's the POSIX compliant version as an alternative:
(Apparently the script does not work if the filenames contain a newline or an escape character `\x1b`.)

```
#!/bin/sh

execHome="intendedMachine"
baseDir="/home/library/projects"
folderNew="output"
folderOld="working"
folderArchive="archive"
workingTypes="jpg
svg
bmp
tiff
psd"

folderNew="$baseDir/$folderNew"
folderOld="$baseDir/$folderOld"
folderArchive="$baseDir/$folderArchive"
nl="
"                   # set to newline character
esc=$(/bin/echo -ne "\033")      # set to escape character
#esc=":"            # if \033 does not work well, try another character

# substitute of reading a hash
# it relies on the context that IFS is set to $nl
read_lut() {
    local i
    local key
    local val
    local ret=""
    for i in $lut; do
        key="${i%${esc}*}"
        val="${i#*${esc}}"
    if [ "$key" = "$1" ]; then
        # loop until the end and use the last value
        ret="$val"
    fi
    done
    echo "$ret"
}

# substitute of writing to a hash
write_lut() {
    lut=$(printf "%s\n%s%c%s" "$lut" "$1" "$esc" "$2")
}

if [ "$(uname -n)" != "$execHome" ]; then
    printf "Executed from %s; Run from %s for proper execution.\n" "$(uname -n)" "$execHome"
    exit
fi

count=$(find "$folderNew" -type f |grep -v "DS_Store" |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'|wc -l)
printf "\nFound/processing %s files in the %s folder\n\n" "$count" "$folderNew"

# determine parent directory name for each project name and create a map for them
ifs_bak="$IFS"
IFS="$nl"
for f in $(find "$folderOld" -type f); do
    proj="${f##*/}"         # remove dirname
    proj="${proj%.*}"               # remove extention
    parent="${f##*$baseDir/}"       # remove pathname until $baseDir
    parent="${parent#*/}"   # strip pathname one-level deeper
    parent="${parent%/*}"   # remove filename
    # now we're mapping "projectOne 1.a" => "House/2018 01" e.g.
#   echo "$proj" "=>" "$parent"     # just for debugging
    write_lut "$proj" "$parent"
done

# iterate over files in A; move to archive directory C and remove files in B
for f in $(find "$folderNew" -type f); do
    proj="${f##*/}"
    proj="${proj%.*}"
    parent=$(read_lut "$proj")
    if [ "$parent" = "" ]; then
        echo "parent of $f not found"   # may not occur but just in case ..
    else
        # move from A to C
        destdir="$folderArchive/$parent"
        mkdir -p -- "$destdir"
        mv -- "$f" "$destdir"

        # remove relevant file(s) in B
        for ext in $workingTypes; do
            oldfile="$folderOld/$parent/$proj.${ext}"
            [ -f "$oldfile" ] && rm -f -- "$oldfile"
        done
    fi
done

# clean-up: remove empty dirs in B
find "$folderOld" -type d -empty -print0 | xargs -r -0 rmdir --

# restore IFS
IFS="$ifs_bak"
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and thorough response.  In deed this executes in an older bash.  It's version 3.2.57.  That was why I indicated POSIX compliance.  I had assumed that would lead to a solution that wouldn't depend on a specific bash version.  I'm thoroughly grateful for your recommendation, and look forward to studying and learning more from you.

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed your requirements. Now I have updated my answer with a POSIX compliant version. POSIX sh lacks in some important features in bash like an array, process substition, etc. and we need to find alternatives.
IMHO bash may not be an appropriate language for complicated task like this due to a lot of limitations and pitfalls, much less POSIX sh.

Comment: Thank you again.  Well done.  So far I'm finding similar results though.  I see the correct mappings taking place(from commented debugging line), but still receive the message of parents not found in the next loop.  I'll run through tonight for more thorough debugging.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I've tested on another platform and have reproduced the similar error you are facing. Although I've not found the root cause, the error can be fixed by assigning the `esc` variable, the field separator, to another one, say `":"`. (The character should not appear in the filenames/pathnames in your directory tree.) I'll keep on studying what is the difference. BR.

Comment: No inconvenience at all.  You've been very helpful, and I'll be studying the work and iterations as reference material as I learn more.  Now that the test script executes according to plan, it's on to production files.  Wish me luck.  I'll report back with results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've found the cause of the bug. It is because of the `sh` built-in `echo` command. Its behavior differs depending the `sh` version and it also differs that of `bash`. I have updated my answer by replacing `echo` with `/bin/echo`. Then it properly sets the variable to the escape character. If you are changing the delimiter to another character, it's okay so far. I'm crossing my fingers for your luck!

Comment: So, the test -empty is not available in bash 3.2.57, and we're still finding all recursive files in the output folder.  Attempting to adjust with -maxdepth 1 to limit recursion.  More to follow.  Getting late for me.

Comment: Running out of time to test/debug.  I'm sure this is the key to the final solution though, so marking complete.  Thanks-a-million.